# Routing all packets through my program?

Tags: java, python, networking, tcp, tunnel

I want to build an application that routes all network traffic (not just HTTP) through my application. Basically, what I want is all the traffic to be given to my application (they should never reach the actual target, my application should handle this), which will in turn be forwarded to a server; same goes for input, just reversed (server -> application -> program which wants an answer). Are there any libraries (or similar stuff) that would make creating the application easier? I'm looking for something that I can use from Python or Java, but if it's really needed, I can learn another language.

Comment: That'd be a firewall with filters. This is **NOT** something you want to try to implement yourself.

Comment: @Bogdacutu: It would be an incredibly complex multi-year project that you'd be unlikely to create without either gaping security flaws, bugs, or both

Comment: @Daenyth: none of those are reasons NOT to try to implement something yourself.  *"Don't try it!  It will be difficult!"*  Where would civilization be if everybody heeded that advice?

Comment: @maerics - Sitting next to a campfire looking up to a starry sky?

Comment: @Rob: I wish!  But seriously, I don't think that discouraging fellow developers from trying something is a good idea in this community; pointing out the challenges and pitfalls is totally valid though.

Comment: @maerics: It depends on the reason. If he needs it for business applications, it seems poor practice to build it from scratch. Obviously if he's just doing it to learn about things then it's fine to proceed, but it really depends on the context.

Comment: @Bogdacutu: Are you doing this just for self-education or do you intend to actually use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to use is a packet capture library, you can us[e pcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html) or its implementation or bindings in [python](http://pylibpcap.sourceforge.net/) or java.

However things like these are ussually implemented at the low level ideally using C, 
Here is a tutorial [Tutorial](http://yuba.stanford.edu/~casado/pcap/section1.html)

**EDIT: In light of your comments you definitely want to take a look at netfilter hooks**

While you are at it you also might want to take a look at [netfilter hooks](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-hacking-HOWTO.html#toc2)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Jpcap](http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/).

Comment: That's just for capturing; my application needs to act like a "gateway".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to route only tcp traffic is actually kind of simple using threads and **sockets**.
You should listen in a different port for every server you want to reach. Either in Java or Python you have to create a "socket" for every port you want to listen in.

For every new connection you create a new connection to the server and create two new threads to handle that connection, one thread will be reading everything from the client and sending it to the server. The other will be reading everything from the server and sending it to the client. When any end of the connection closes it, you close the other and end both threads.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this on Linux, you should consider using a TUN/TAP device, which is a very handy tool for intercepting network traffic for custom processing.  Here's a basic tutorial if you're unfamiliar  http://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/